# Can't find the reason for losing 8 rep points. How can I find the reason?

Tags: support

I was away for few days and left my browser opened on Stack Overflow - my reputation was 2240 points.

When I returned (~14 days), I've refreshed my browser (using F5) and saw my reputation went down by 8 points and now is on 2232.

I searched the reputation tag in my profile to see if there was a downvote or points removal (from user deletion) but couldn't find any, actually i've seen from 10-Aug +20 points and no negative records.

Can you help me understand why i lost 8 points?

Comment: Probably 4 questions that you had approved suggested edits on from when you were below 2,000 reputation have been deleted. You should be able to find out for definite if you tick the "Show removed posts" checkbox at the bottom of your reputation tab.

Comment: @JonK - you are correct, after clicking, i see the 8 points removal. btw: one of the deduction is due to "migrated" - what does it mean?

Comment: That would be a question that was moved from Stack Overflow to another site in the Stack Exchange network

Comment: Quantum noise? Who cares? It is 8 points. You didn't lose any privileges. It would have taken less time to answer a question and get more than 8 points.

Comment: @CodyGray - it is a simple question of knowledge - now I've learnt about the "show removed posts" check box. it is not about the 8 points themselves, but on "how can i find the reason?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you can click on the "Show removed posts" checkbox on the bottom of your reputation tab and it will display addition details but here's what happened.

Your reputation loss was due to 4 posts being removed.  All 4 posts you had suggested edits on which were accepted 4 x 2 = 8.

3 of the posts were deleted via the [Roomba job](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) as they were negatively scored questions with no answers and older than 30 days.   The last question was migrated to another site and the stub was deleted causing the rep loss.